# Loader displays while DOM is updating

Tags: google-app-maker

I've got a page where I am using relations to pull in various items

1. Dropdown lets you select an employee
2. Second dropdown lets you pick a timeframe
3. The table then pulls items related to the employee + timeframe

The problem is that the loader disappears before the screen is refereshed with the data from #3.

I've tried binding the visibility of the loader to multiple datasources
`widget.datasource.loading || second_datasource.loading || ...`
 but I'm struggling to get it to appear for the duration of the load. Is there anything I can do to have it appear until my client is fully updated? Do I need to be manually manipulating visibility with jQuery or is there is an App Maker binding I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

At this time App Maker doesn't provide any global variable (something like `@app.isBusy`) that would help you to tackle the problem, there is also no easy way to discover all datasources being loaded... So, the answer will be: you need to thoroughly investigate your code to discover all things you are loading. One more trick that I can recommend is specifying datasources explicitly:

```javascript
@app.datasources.DsOne.loading ||
@app.datasources.DsTwo.loading ||
@app.datasources.DsThree.loading ||
...
```